# How to push_back an object properly?

Tags: c++, object, vector

Hi I have an issue with pushing back object to a vector of objects.

```
class boxes {
protected:
    int x = 0;
public:
    void setx (int input) {
        x = input;
    }
    int getx () {
        return x;
    }
} box;

box.setx(5);
vector <boxes> tetris;
tetris.push_back(box);
cout << box.getx();
cout << tetris.back().getx();
```

Why the two prints have different values? The first one is giving me x=5, the second x=0.

Comment: Can you put a runnable example? Which compiler are you using? Ideally, it should be print 5 for both. Push_back will make a copy of the pushed object, and the default copy constructor make a bit-wise copy of the source object. May be some compiler optimization is on play here. Check it here http://ideone.com/azrCfy  . They are printing same value.

Comment: "Why the two prints have different values " - they don't, [**See it live**](http://ideone.com/GbnzXb), and provide toolchain info.

Comment: Found the bug guys. In my copy constructor, I had forgotten to include the variable x. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If you provide a copy constructor, make sure you implement it correctly. My bug was there.